# Outlook Addin "TO/CC/BCC" Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook-addin

Will i be able to use the "TO/CC/BCC" Textbox in outlook addin?
I want to add a recepient box for which i need all the functionalities of the above control.
Any help on this?

Comment: is smtp client is convenient for you?

Comment: Whatever is possible, I ll try everything

Comment: you are excepting a function/method to send mail with to/cc/bcc with attachment na?

Comment: No I need to have the "TO/CC/BCC" textbox control with all the existing functionalities in my outlook addin form

Answer (score 1):

I used this a long time ago. Check it out:

```
Outlook.Application oApp;
Outlook.MailItem mailItem;
oApp = new Outlook.Application();
mailItem = oApp.CreateItem(0);
Outlook.Recipient recipent = this.mailItem.Recipients.Add("sample@mail.com");
recipent.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo;
mailItem.Display();
```

For CC and BCC:

```
recipent.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olCC;
recipent.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC;
```